# host mutliple servers on the same port?

Tags: networking, port, ports

Okay, I have two physical computers on my one network, they are both running CSGO servers. Let's call them Server A, and Server B. Server A and Server B are both set to bind to the same port. But, they both can't because that's not "not how it works". Therefore, Server A is showing up online, but Server B isn't.

Here's my question: How can I make both of these servers bind to the same external port? (Hosting on my home internet)

Comment: I'm really suspecting that when you say "bind to port" you're actually talking about port-forwarding on a NAT router, and _not_ about actually binding a socket. (I'm also suspecting that your both computers have private IP addresses, and you're trying to receive connections from the internet.) Is that guess correct?

Answer (score 2):

**The general answer to your question is "you can't".**   An analogy to what you are asking is "2 people can not drive 1 car to 2 different places at the same time.

(I do not know anything about CSGO, but I do know about networking, so I can't advise on specifics of CSGO).

There are ways of working arround multiple devices wanting to use the same port.  The options which will almost always work, would be to connect the CSGO server to a VPN which provides a static IP address and allows incoming requests.  This will bypass the router port limitation.  In essence it gives you a second IP address to use for the second server (so think a second car in the analogy).  Unfortunately this does not come free.   [ You could possibly gerry-rig your own AWS minimal EC2 instance with OpenVPN and get something freeish for a year, but steep learning curve ].

Other solutions to the general problem of running 2 servers **(which are unlikely to work here)** are

(a) use different IP addesses for CSGO server. 
 (b) create a proxy server which can terminate the sessions and then use information in the packets to direct to the appropriate server (this is a role often served by a reverse proxy).